# "Could not open input file: bin/magento" issue after composer update 2.4.2 -> 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

We are updating Magento form 2.4.2 to 2.4.3

After running composer update and everything looks like it's updated succesfully, I get the following message in bash.

"Could not open input file: bin/magento"

How can I fix this?

...
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
114 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
File doesn't exist: bin/magento
Check "chmod" section in composer.json of magento/magento2-base package.

Comment: Can you please select only one of your answers to keep around and delete the others? This isn't a forum, and you should not use answers to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

When I check the "bin" folder there is no magento file

Answer (score 0):

When I do a composer downgrade to version 2.4.2 - everything is working fine again

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is due to wrong file permissions.

How do I set the right and safe filepermissions for Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

yes-its showing this error could not open input file:bin/magento may be you are not running this command in magento 2 root directory.Actually in magento 2 root directory - we have folder called bin - so based on  that file and reference it running commands.
So here i would suggest you to go into the magento 2 root directory by using CD command
then run the given commands it will works !

For more details
[Installation guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's showing the error **"could not open input file bin/magento"** because you have not run the command in the Magento root directory.

Actually Magento root directory we have folder **bin** so based on that file it running the command.

So please run the command on the Magento root directory.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

this solved the issue :-)

$ cd /var/www/html/magento2 && sudo find var vendor
pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && sudo find
var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + &&
sudo chown -R :apache . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento

See also https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034224232-File-permissions-readiness-check-issues